# How to quote a string dynamically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This kinda funny, i want to quote a string value for a function but javascript throws this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

This my code

```
var val = "Testing String";
var table_row = "<tr><td><a href='#' onclick='test('"+val+"')'>Row1</a></td></tr>";

function test( val ){
  alert( val );
}
```

The table row get created fine with the test function bound well with onClick event.
But when i click on the created link i get

```
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

The Value within the test function should be a quoted string.

Note: If i remove the concatenation of the val string, and pass is as a string like this

```
table_row = "<tr><td><a href='#' onClick='test(\"Testing String\")' >Row1</a></td>";
```

... it works

Where am i goofing?

Gath.

Comment: Does `"..."Row1"..."` really work?

Answer (score 1):

Then in your original script also escape `"`:

```
var test = "\"test string\"";
```

Comment: The original string (first line) does not contain any quotation marks to be escaped:

Answer (score 1):

i thing it ll help u sir,,,,

> if row1 is variable
>
> u can add by `'+Row1+'` seperator,
>
> or else directly use bellow code;

```
var table_row = '<tr><td><a href="#" onClick="test(\'Testing String\')" >Row1</a></td>';
        //alert("++++++++++++"+table_row+"++++++++++++");
```

see ya ,,,

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
var val = "Testing String";
var table_row = "<tr><td><a href='#' onclick='test('"+val+"')'>Row1</a></td></tr>";
```

Should `table_row` not be

```
"<tr><td><a href='#' onclick='test('Testing String')'>Row1</a></td></tr>"
```

so the onclick attribute is only `'test('`, because `'` ends it?

Try:

```
var table_row = "<tr><td><a href='#' onclick=\"test('"+val+"')\">Row1</a></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This what i did and now working fine;

```
var val = "Testing String";
table_row = "<tr><td><a href='#' onclick='test(\""+val+"\")'>Row1</a></td></tr>";

function test( val ){
 alert( val)   // Displays "Testing String"
}
```

Thanks for your patience.